# Converting Future[SomeObject] into json

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-json

I'm using scala and writing my domain objects to json. I use Play's Json Combinators like this:

```
implicit def opensHighlights: Writes[Option[OpensHighlights]] =
  (
    (__ \ 'header).write[String] and
    (__ \ 'topDeviceForOpens).write[String] and
    (__ \ 'percentage).write[String] and
    (__ \ 'percentageOf).write[String])(opensMaybe => {
      val header = Messages("email.summary.highlights.device.opens")
      val percentageOf = Messages("email.summary.highlights.ofAll.opens")
      opensMaybe match {
        case Some(opens) => (
          header,
          deviceTypeName(opens.topDevice),
          Percentage(opens.opensOnThisDevice, opens.totalOpens).stringValue(),
          percentageOf)
        case None => (header, NotApplicable, "0.00", percentageOf)
      }
    })
```

I'm using this writer in a larger writer:

```
implicit def summaryHighlightsWrites: Writes[SummaryHighlights] = {
      (
        (__ \ "google").write[Either[GoogleError, GoogleHighlights]] and
        (__ \ "dateWithHighestClickToOpenRate").write[Option[DateHighlights]] and
        (__ \ "subjectLine").write[Option[SubjectLineHighlights]] and
        (__ \ "location").write[Option[LocationHighlights]] and
        (__ \ "link").write[Option[LinkHighlights]] and
        (__ \ "deviceForOpens").write[Option[OpensHighlights]] and
        (__ \ "deviceForClicks").write[Option[ClicksHighlights]])(summary => {
          val result = for {
            google <- summary.google
            dateRange <- summary.dateRange
            subjectLine <- summary.subjectLine
            location <- summary.location
            link <- summary.link
            opensDevice <- summary.opensDevice
            clicksDevice <- summary.clicksDevice
          } yield (google, dateRange, subjectLine, location, link, opensDevice, clicksDevice)

          Await.result(result, 10 seconds)
        })
    }
```

And here is the SummaryHighlights class:

```
case class SummaryHighlights(
  google: Future[Either[GoogleError, GoogleHighlights]],
  dateRange: Future[Option[DateHighlights]],
  subjectLine: Future[Option[SubjectLineHighlights]],
  location: Future[Option[LocationHighlights]],
  link: Future[Option[LinkHighlights]],
  opensDevice: Future[Option[OpensHighlights]],
  clicksDevice: Future[Option[ClicksHighlights]])
```

I need these fields to each be a `Future` because they have independent sources and can fail/succeed independently.

I want to remove that explicit await. I want to move the await on the future from `summaryHighlightsWrites` to some other piece of code that calls this writer. Like a Play controller.

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Creating a `Writes` for a `Future` doesn't make sense. You need to provide more context for your problem. Where is the `Future` coming from, and where are you using it? My guess is most likely within a Play controller that needs a `Future[Result]`, but I have no idea from your question.

Comment: As mentioned by @LimbSoup you can not convert a `Future` to Json. Instead you can `map` the future with a function and in that function you can convert your tuple to a json. Then you will have a `Future[Json]` which you can serve easily with play controllers (Use `Action.async` for example)

Comment: Yeah, @LimbSoup, this is my intention, to serve it to a play controller.

Comment: What is the compilation error?

Comment: @tuxdna, it's a type mismatch: 
 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[(String, String, String, String)]
 required: (String, String, String, String)

Comment: I've realized that my question was not very clear, in that it was not detailing my exact situation. I have updated the question. I hope it is more clear

Comment: Having case class fields that are `Future`s is not a good idea. That's just going to create a huge mess.

Answer (score 3):

Supposing you have a method `highlights` that returns a `Future[Option[OpensHighlights]]` and you have an implicit `Writes[Option[OpensHighlights]]` in defined in scope, you would do something like this:

```
def highlights: Future[Option[OpensHighlights]] = ...

def asyncJson = Action.async { request =>
    highlights.map { result =>
        Ok(Json.toJson(result))
    }
}
```

The `Future[...]` must be mapped to a `Future[Result]` returned within `Action.async`, which will specially handles `Future[Result]`s as opposed to plain `Result`s.